# Storybook 6 decorator pass props to story not working

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm using `@storybook/react v6.1.21`. I want to have the option to pass state to my stories using `state` and `setState` props.

This is how I defined my decorator:

```
//preview.js
export const decorators = [
    Story => {
        const [state, setState] = useState();
        return <Story state={state} setState={setState} />;
    }
];

// mycomponent.stories.tsx

export const TwoButtons = ({ state, setState }) => (
    <ButtonGroup
        buttons={[
            { label: 'One',value: 'one'},
            { label: 'Two', value: 'two' }
        ]}
        selectedButton={state}
        onClick={val => setState(val)}
    />
);
```

But for some reason state and setState are undefined in the story. I had a similar setup working in Storybook v5.
Any idea what i'm missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[From the docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args):

> parameters.passArgsFirst: In Storybook 6+, we pass the args as the first argument to the story function. The second argument is the “context” which contains things like the story parameters etc.

You should be able to access `state` and `setState` by making a small adjustment to the story function signature:

```
//preview.js
export const decorators = [
    Story => {
        const [state, setState] = useState();
        return <Story state={state} setState={setState} />;
    }
];

// mycomponent.stories.tsx

export const TwoButtons = (args, context) => {
  const { state, setState } = context;

  return (
    <ButtonGroup
        buttons={[
            { label: 'One',value: 'one'},
            { label: 'Two', value: 'two' }
        ]}
        selectedButton={state}
        onClick={val => setState(val)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks. But can't find it in docs... Do you have reference?